# Каким членом предложения будет являться слово "нелегкий" ?

Tags: синтаксис

**Нелегкий** это труд - учеба.

Answer (score 1):

А почему не так: труд - подлежащее, нелегкий - сказуемое, учеба - приложение (какой труд нелегкий?).

Answer (score 0):

Можно трактовать как часть составного именного сказуемого, можно - как определение к предикативу "труд". Смотря как вопрос задать.

Comment: Нет. Не вопрос здесь главное. Главное, какой смысл вкладывает автор в высказывание. Здесь важно не то, что учеба - труд (это всем известно), а то, что труд этот нелегкий. Смысловой центр высказывания заключается именно в зависимом слове "нелегкий". Ну а дальше строго, как учили в школе, по учебнику ) 

См.  Составное именное сказуемое: Неоднословное выражение именной части, п. 1б http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#312

Comment: Да, подумавши соглашусь

Comment: @mueller, а Вы расскажете подробно, с чем это Вы согласились? 
Одним словом, чем имеено является "нелегкий".

Ничего не хочу сказать про спрашивающего, но среди читающих наверняка найдутся те, кто в другую школу ходил и не по Литневской учился. 
Дело, конечно, не в Литневской с её вечными заморочками, но отсылать к учеьникам, не сказав, что именно там надо искать... Автора идеи боюсь беспокоить, но ежели вдруг она сама сможет объяснить, то не возражаю. )))  

Я лично вижу здесь именно определение к "труд", ибо исхожу из принципа наибольшей простоты, если не доказано иное.

Answer (score -3):

Для начала нужно посмотреть на главные члены предложения. Это *Труд* и *Учёба*. Смотрим дальше... Ставим вопрос от главного слова к подлежащему. На данный момент главным членом предложения является слово *Труд*, то есть от него и ставить. ***Труд(какой?).**
**Нелёгкий.** Значит получается, что слово *Нелёгкий* в данной ситуации имя прилагательное.

Comment: Нелегкий - имя прилагательное, да, а член предложения - сказуемое.

Учеба - это нелегкий труд. 

В исходном варианте предложения присутствует инверсия, что, думаю, и стало причиной затруднения )

Comment: Кстати, при инверсии тире не ставится.

Comment: Тире при инверсии не ставится (хотя и допустимо при наличии паузы), "если оба они [подлежащее и сказуемое] выражены неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом) или если один из главных членов выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — неопределенной формой глагола ...  Какое счастье сына обнимать!" (Розенталь).

Comment: Посмею добавить, что Розенталь приводит и такой пример отсутствия тире при инверсии: "Интересный человек наш сосед" (это в его старом учебнике "Русский язык для поступающих  в вузы"). Здесь, как видим, инфинитивом и не пахнет

Comment: Ещё пример инверсии:"Вся Россия наш сад" Чехов. Именно сад - это Россия, а не наоборот.

Comment: Там сказано: 

Тире не ставится
...5. Иногда при обратном порядке главных членов предложения, т.е. если сказуемое предшествует подлежащему:

^ Интересный человек наш сосед.

— "иногда" не означает "всегда".

Comment: Да, конечно. Я просто добавил к тому, что Вы написали. Возможно, в разных книгах Розенталь приводил разные примеры.